# Java почему используется Arrays.toString для массивов типа String при выводе на экран?

Tags: java, строки, вывод

Имеем:

```java
int scores = {1, 2, 3};
char[] symbols = {'a', 'b'};
String str = {"Hello", "World"};
```

Понимаю, что при выводе на экран массива типа `int` мы должны использовать `Arrays.toString()`, чтобы  массив преобразовать в строку и `System.out.println()` показал массив а не адрес памяти.

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores)); // [1, 2, 3]

System.out.println(scores); // [I@5e9f23b4
```

Так как массив из символов тоже можно считать строкой можно передать массив символов как аргумент в `System.out.println()` и все будет норм.

```java
System.out.println(symbols); // ab
```

Так почему же тот же принцип не работает с массивами типа `String`, и почему я должен использовать `Arrays.toString()`?

```java
System.out.println(str); // [Ljava.lang.String;@5e9f23b4

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str)); // ["Hello", "World"]
```

Comment: Ваш код даже не скомпилируется по следующим причинам:
1. отсутствует точка с запятой во второй строке (но это не суть);
2. вы объявляете переменные не как массив (без []).
А для метода println() имеется спец. перегрузка для char[], для остальных случаев срабатывает перегрузка для Object.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Это просто пример который я написал в редакторе сайта. Я понимаю вас, но это никак не меняет суть вопроса.

Comment: я вас понимаю, просто это несколько отводит в сторону от анализа проблемы тех, кто пытается вам помочь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

потому что для вывода `char` - специальный метод в `System.out.println` со своей обработкой

А массив `String` воспринимается как массив объектов. И там вызывается как раз `String.valueOf(str)` для получения строки вывода

А как раз `Arrays.toString(str)` уже непосредственно преобразовывает все значения массива в строку